# PKTGEN Cannot RUN connected-6-DX

Tags: dpdk

## Set up

Pktgen version: 21.02.0
DPDK version 20.11.3
OS: Centos 7.7
kernel: 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64
NIC: Mellanox

### Issue

When I run pktgen 21.02, I got error messages as following

```
Copyright(c) <2010-2021>, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved. Powered by DPDK  
EAL: Detected 96 lcore(s)  
EAL: Detected 4 NUMA nodes  
EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK  
EAL: /lib64/libibverbs.so.1: version `IBVERBS_PRIVATE_25' not found (required by /lib64/libmlx4.so.1)  
EAL: FATAL: Cannot init plugins  
EAL: Cannot init plugins  

[CMD]./Builddir/app/pktgen -c 0xff -n 3 -a 0000:3b:00.1 -d librte_net_mlx5.so -- -p 0x1 -P -m "[1:2].0"
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: please update with NIC version and firmware, there is also an error log `EAL: /lib64/libibverbs.so.1: version `IBVERBS_PRIVATE_25' not found (required by /lib64/libmlx4.so.1) ` which means you are missing libverbs on your system. Please install the same.

Comment: I am able to run pktgen with MLX-5 PMD. Hope the answer helped you, if yes please accept and upvote to close.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error logs from EAL, it is found that `EAL: /lib64/libibverbs.so.1: version` IBVERBS_PRIVATE_25' not found (required by /lib64/libmlx4.so.1)`. This means the ***system used for testing either does not have the libibverbs installed or the path is not set***.

The recommended solution is to either

1. install the libibverbs-devel package for the Linux Distro. or
2. manually find the library using `find / -name libibverbs.so*`. Then append the path to environment variable ***LD_LIBRARY_PATH*** .

Hence this is not Pktgen 21.02 error but missing dependencies